# Normal alarm clocks: how to make them ring softer?

Tags: acoustics, time

This is a stupid yet interesting question. The best way I discovered till now is wrap it up in a sweater, and put it under bed. However that way I couldn’t access the snooze button later. I tried blocking the sound opening but, nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Put a pillow on it or drop it into a bucket with water.

Comment: The bucket idea is nice, but i am not sure, if the clock can withstand that. Especially when it has an electronic circuit within it.

Comment: Well, clock settings and survival was not covered in question. Another approach, is if clock is relatively small - you can put it in a vacuum flask. There's a vacuum inside, so it perfectly would isolate sounds.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. Sound doesn’t travel through vacuum, so this will work 